My pgbouncer on docker container is not working properly
I have running containers and they are working properly. But for some reason, the requests are not distributed to pgbouncerc.
After command "docker logs " I am getting this output though I have made many requests to a database
2024-11-05 09:53:41.229 UTC [1] LOG stats: 0 xacts/s, 0 queries/s, 0 client parses/s, 0 server parses/s, 0 binds/s, in 0 B/s, out 0 B/s, xact 0 us, query 0 us, wait 0 us
2024-11-05 09:54:41.229 UTC [1] LOG stats: 0 xacts/s, 0 queries/s, 0 client parses/s, 0 server parses/s, 0 binds/s, in 0 B/s, out 0 B/s, xact 0 us, query 0 us, wait 0 us
2024-11-05 09:55:41.230 UTC [1] LOG stats: 0 xacts/s, 0 queries/s, 0 client parses/s, 0 server parses/s, 0 binds/s, in 0 B/s, out 0 B/s, xact 0 us, query 0 us, wait 0 us
2024-11-05 09:56:41.230 UTC [1] LOG stats: 0 xacts/s, 0 queries/s, 0 client parses/s, 0 server parses/s, 0 binds/s, in 0 B/s, out 0 B/s, xact 0 us, query 0 us, wait 0 us
2024-11-05 09:57:41.230 UTC [1] LOG stats: 0 xacts/s, 0 queries/s, 0 client parses/s, 0 server parses/s, 0 binds/s, in 0 B/s, out 0 B/s, xact 0 us, query 0 us, wait 0 us

Probably routing is not working properly. I have checked many times haproxy and docker-compose but I couldn't find the reason causing this behaviour.
Here is my haproxy.conf file:
global
    log stdout format raw local0

defaults
    log     global
    mode    tcp
    option  tcplog
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client  50000ms
    timeout server  50000ms

frontend pgbouncer_frontend
    bind *:5432
    default_backend pgbouncer_backend

backend pgbouncer_backend
    balance roundrobin
    server pgbouncer1 pgbouncer1:6432 check
    server pgbouncer2 pgbouncer2:6432 check
    server pgbouncer3 pgbouncer3:6432 check

below is my docker-compose.yml file
version: '3.8'

x-environment:
  &default-env
    POSTGRESQL_HOST: ip_address
    POSTGRESQL_USERNAME: username
    POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD: password
    PGBOUNCER_DATABASE: database
    PGBOUNCER_POOL_MODE: session
    PGBOUNCER_IGNORE_STARTUP_PARAMETERS: "extra_float_digits"

services:
  haproxy:
    image: haproxy:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
    depends_on:
      - pgbouncer1
      - pgbouncer2
      - pgbouncer3

  pgbouncer1:
    image: bitnami/pgbouncer:latest
    restart: always
    environment: *default-env

  pgbouncer2:
    image: bitnami/pgbouncer:latest
    restart: always
    environment: *default-env

  pgbouncer3:
    image: bitnami/pgbouncer:latest
    restart: always
    environment: *default-env


What I have tried:
I tried to connect to a database with command:
telnet <ip_address> <port>

After connecting this way my docker logs  changed to
49.12.193.95:48672 [05/Nov/2024:07:43:25.831] pgbouncer_frontend pgbouncer_backend/pgbouncer2 1/0/50019 0 cD 1/1/0/0/0 0/0
49.12.193.95:41276 [05/Nov/2024:07:44:27.391] pgbouncer_frontend pgbouncer_backend/pgbouncer3 1/0/41289 53 -- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0
172.18.0.1:39674 [05/Nov/2024:07:55:22.749] pgbouncer_frontend pgbouncer_backend/pgbouncer1 1/0/2 25 -- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0
172.18.0.1:37148 [05/Nov/2024:07:55:35.243] pgbouncer_frontend pgbouncer_backend/pgbouncer2 1/0/10921 612 -- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0

